# Ember-CLI error on changing a CSS file

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs

I'm trying out Ember-CLI, and have encountered my first obscure problem (there were others, but… they're fixed). On trying to save a change in the app.css file, this happens:

```
file changed styles/app.css
EEXIST, file already exists '/Users/admin/projects/saves/tmp/caching-writer-dest-dir_fjlhTg.tmp'
Error: EEXIST, file already exists '/Users/admin/projects/saves/tmp/caching-writer-dest-dir_fjlhTg.tmp'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.symlinkSync (fs.js:852:18)
    at symlink (/Users/admin/projects/saves/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/symlink-or-copy/index.js:82:14)
    at Function.symlinkOrCopySync (/Users/admin/projects/saves/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/symlink-or-copy/index.js:58:5)
    at /Users/admin/projects/saves/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-sourcemap-concat/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:103:21
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/Users/admin/projects/saves/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:489:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/Users/admin/projects/saves/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:501:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/Users/admin/projects/saves/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:472:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/Users/admin/projects/saves/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1290:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

The closest match I can find is [this ember-cli issue](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/265).

### Update and fix:

I tried the following:

```
rm -rf node_modules tmp dist && npm cache clean
ember install
```

But the issue persisted (after also trying the add `rimraf` to dependencies and doing `npm install rimraf`, now removed again).

### The actual solution

Then it occurred to me that I needed to `npm update ember-cli`, *then* the above commands again, after which all is working now :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** As per **raytiley's** comments, the issue is not with rimraf, and the offender (broccoli-caching-writer) should be fixed soon. Therefore, at this time, Step 1 should not be necessary if you're experiencing this problem now.

See the comments in the [Github Issue](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3413)

---

This looks like a recent issue with dependencies, specifically rimraf. Currently, users are having success with this solution:

1. First, add this to your package.json file: **(Not needed anymore)**

   ```
   "dependencies": {
     "rimraf": "2.2.8"
   }
   ```
2. Secondly, type this into the command line to re-install your node items

   ```
   rm -rf node_modules tmp dist && npm cache clean
   ember install
   ```

Hope that helps!

Comment: FWIW, at the time of writing this I still had to add the rimraf dependency. After that your instructions worked - thanks!